# Call a python script with flask: what is the best way?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, flask

I am fairly new to flask and therefore I have a question regarding the logic behind my code and if my thought process makes sense.

I have an old python script, that takes a lot of data, processes it and then produces a plot with matplotlib. This works fine.

Now I want to build a web application, where a user selects specific input parameters, clicks the submit button, my server checks (with the help of sqlite) if there already exists a plot/the data to make the plot with those parameters, if yes then make it downloadable by the user.

If this plot/the data does not exist, my flask application calls my python script and the new plot/data for it will get created, uploaded to sqlite and then the user can download it from the web application.

As you can see in my code so far the python script is an external one and my plan is to not include it in my views from my flask app, does this make sense? Should I call an external script here or just copy the code directly to my views? (I wanted to avoid it so far since it's a pretty big script)

My logic so far looks like this:

```
# this part works well so far, I get the user input here and redirect it to the specific page
@app.route('/plot', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def get_plot():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        input1 = request.form['input1']
        input2 = request.form['input2']
        input3 = request.form['input3']
        return redirect('plot/{}/{}/{}/'.format(input1, input2, input3))
    else:
        return render_template('plot.html')

# here it get's a bit tricky for me
@app.route('/plot/<input1>/<input2>/<input3>/')
def create_plot(input1='1', input2='2', input3='3'):
    try:
        db = get_db(DB_PLOT)
        cur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE param1 = {} AND param2={}'.format(input1, input2, input3)) # get all the data from the table
    except:
        return "Plot not found !"
        # CALL THE EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT HERE?
        cur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE param1 = {} AND param2={}'.format(input1, input2, input3)) # python script should have updated the database, so i can call the data here

    data = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_plot.html', data=data)
```

Furthermore, I have another question:
As said my python script, which I've only ever used so far on its own, takes raw data, manipulates it and then creates a plot with matplotlib.
When I want to implement it in my web application, should I still create the plot with the python script, upload the plot to sqlite and then get the image from sqlite with the web application OR should I just upload the manipulated data, then download this data from sqlite and create the plot with flask?

In the end, I want to make it possible for the user to download the plot as .jpg and .pdf file.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module to achieve this. Depending on how long your script takes to generate the plot you should consider returning a page to the user asking him to refresh the page after some time until the plot is available (you could also auto refresh using javascript frequently). A view function which takes too long can be a problem because the amount of threads Flask uses to handle requests is limited, this could make your application unavailable if too many users are generating plots at the same time.

Returning before calling your script won't work obviously.

```
return "Plot not found !"
# CALL THE EXTERNAL PYTHON SCRIPT HERE?
```

You also need to insert a entry in the database before starting to work on the plot generation so no other user can run your script again with the same parameters.

Your `except` case (when the plot is not is the database already) would look something like this **(probably vulerable to SQL injection)**:

```
# write entry to the database with parameters but without plot
db.execute('INSERT INTO {} (param1, param2, param3) VALUES ({}, {}, {})'.format(table_name, input1, input2, input3))
# start process which does it's calculations in another process and
# updates the table we just inserted with the plot when finished
p = Popen(['/path/to/script.py', input1, input2, input3], stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True)

return "Plot is beeing generated ..., please refresh page until the plot is available"
```

The script generating the plot would then update the entry as follows **(probably vulerable to SQL injection)**:

```
db.execute('UPDATE {} SET plot_blob = {} WHERE param1 = {} AND param2 = {} AND param3 = {}'.format(table_name, binary_image_data, input1, input2, input3))
```

NOTES:

1. You can build the URL with `url_for` which might be neater:

   ```
   return redirect(url_for('create_plot', input1=input1, input2=input2, input3=input3))
   ```
2. Your SQL query is probably vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), although the library your using might handle this. I don't know which it is.